# Python: C style inner loop in python

Tags: javascript, python, loops

i'm working on a nlp project, i'm at the clustering level where i'd like to pair documents against each other. I'd like to translate the following logic in python. but for some strange reasons, i cant wrap my head around this one.

```
var number = [0,1,2,3,4]
for(var i=0; i<number.length; i++){
    for(var j=i; j<number.length; j++){
        console.log(i + "vs"+ j)
    }
}
```

**output:** 0vs0 0vs1 0vs2 0vs3 0vs4 1vs1 1vs2 1vs3 1vs4 2vs2 2vs3 2vs4 3vs3 3vs4 4vs4

**Please what's the python equivalent of the above code.**

Comment: Hint: `for i in range(...)`…

Comment: yes i tried this, but the inner loop uses a variable from the outer loop. at least try implementing it before down voting. for j in range(i) would yield nothing as i would be 0 in the initial loop.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `range` again to replicate the *from i to number.length* logic…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
numbers = [0,1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    for j in range(i, len(numbers)):
        print("{} vs {}".format(i, j))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
number = [0,1,2,3,4]
for i in range(len(number)):
    for j in range(i, len(number)):
        print(i , "vs" , j)
```

Comment: Does not replicate `var j=i; j<number.length; j++` correctly.

Comment: `i` is still incorrect; `i` is *0 to number.length*, not the members of `number`.

Comment: Still doesn't replicate the original code - the values for `i` are not taken from `number`